# How to sort an Array List in an order according to our requirement

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections, jquery-ui-sortable

The List which contains data is in an order of

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
list.add('R'); 
list.add('L');
list.add('H');
list.add('A');
```

If I have to display the list in an order of L,H,R,A.

I tried to add each list value in a LinkedHashMap and and added all in another Linked Hashmap according to the requirement.

Is there any other best way that I can sort this.

Comment: use Comparator interface.

Comment: Can the order(s) you seek be defined mathematically? Eg lexical order? If so it can be implemented in an implementation of the Comparator interface as Prashant suggested, and sorted using Collections.sort

Comment: @copeg could you please show an example please,I am really confused

Comment: The sorting section in the java tutorials has quite a few examples: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/#sorting

Comment: I couldnt resolve , can anyone help me to resolve in a decent coding standards please

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.util.Collections.sort method, pass the array and a comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<String>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            // write your code to decide the order, return negative value for element that you want to appear before another element, zero for equality. same at compareTo works.
        }

    });
```

So, if you would like to sort only the LRHA letters, you can do the following (and i assume that any other string will be placed in the end)

```
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        list.add('R'); 
        list.add('L');
        list.add('H');
        list.add('A');    

        Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<String>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                if(s1 == null)
                    return 2;
                if(s2 == null)
                    return -2;

                if(s1.equals("L")) return -1;
                if(s2.equals("L")) return 1;
                if(s1.equals("H")) return -1;
                if(s2.equals("H")) return 1;
                if(s1.equals("R")) return -1;
                if(s2.equals("R")) return 1;
                if(s1.equals("A")) return -1;
                if(s2.equals("A")) return 1;
                return 2;
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks ,How i will passs s1 and s2 parameters? Can you show a complete code please to get the correct flow ?

Comment: you don't, as you can see, Collections.sort gets an array to sort and and an implementation of Comparable which will be used to sort. You can copy paste my example and it should work for you, try to understand what i did here but it is simple.

Comment: Thanks , I understood , so the next doubt is If the first list contains only R and L , and If i go for the same LHRA order , will this throw any exceptions ?

Comment: If the list is [L,R] then it will use the compare("L","R") and return -1, thus keep it [L,R]. If the list is [R,L] then it will return 1 and switch their places. It  will never throw exception since we check for nulls and put them in the end if found any.

Comment: Thanks a million, I will give a try and check

Comment: Yes, superb, great , Thanks a million